# How to return 2 values from a text link using shadowbox to parent page form

Tags: jquery, shadowbox

I have a form where i need to put 2 values that will be selected from a shadowbox modal window.

the problem im having is it will be a list of probably HUNDREDS of values listed and paginated.

how can i return 2 values with a single click without using forms?

parent page:

```
<input name="id" type="hidden" value="" />
<input name="data" type="text" readonly="true" />
```

Shadowbox printout:

```
<?php
$total = count($_parameters);
for($i = 0; $i < $total;$i++) {
 echo $_parameters[$i] ['id'] . ", " . $_parameters[$i] ['data'] . "<br />";
}
```

the shadowbox printout indeed needs an href of sorts, i know, where i can have the 2 values, one for the id and another for the data.

the id value have to populate the hidden field, the data value the textbox

i've been banging my head over this for over 4 hours with no luck

based on http://shadowbox-js.com/forum.html#nabble-td4019963|a4806279
it can be done with forms, but that method (sorry im not a javascript expert) my thoughts go to have a function for each result, with a form for each result, which seems ridiculously unreasonable.

sorry maybe my question is really noobish, or maybe foolish, but all help is appreciated.

Comment: You question is a bit confusing. Are you opening a php page in the shadowbox and trying to get the values from it? Maybe a little more code and an example of what you are trying to accomplish would help.

Answer (score 0):

Using a click function you can return both data. You can use split function to split the data in to (so you get a id and data). You should put every line in div tag or something.

```
$(".your_list").click(function() { var data = $(this).text().split(",");  });
```

ok there you have it, data[0] is your id and data[1] is you data.